# Composer escapeshellarg() has been disabled for security reasons

Tags: server, composer-php, cpanel, linode

Hey I have a server on [linode.com](https://www.linode.com/) (Centos 7). I installed `cpanel` and composer in my server, when I run this command (via ssh) for creating a blank symfony project,

```
composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition '~2.6'
```

It outputs this:

```
Installing symfony/framework-standard-edition (v2.7.4)
  - Installing symfony/framework-standard-edition (v2.7.4)
    Downloading: 100%         



  [ErrorException]                                         
  escapeshellarg() has been disabled for security reasons
```

How can i fix this?

I don't have much knowledge on server moreover it's my first server, if it's because of `cpanel` I think it will do it again and again in future, is `cpanel` an obstruction for me?

Comment: You might consider posting the solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed it by editing my `php.ini` file.

You can find your `php.ini` location with this command:

```
php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File"
```

I searched `escapesshellarg`, and found it in `disable_functions=`. I deleted it from `disable_functions` and that fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use php -n, no php.ini file will be used.

Enabling escapeshellarg could be a security problem with mod_php or php-fpm.